# external page and iframe issue

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis

I have 2 websites hosted on windows server 2012. One website is using asp.net while other is wordpress. I want to embed asp.net page in wordpress. But, it is not showing anything. I did some research and came to know that perhaps, I have to allow permission for external website. Please guide me how to do it, should I add anything in web.config? I added below in asp.net but it did not help

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">  
</head>
```

Please guide, how to allow external website in iframe?

The iframe looks like below:

[iframe mydomain.com/signIn.aspx 640px 400px]

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown us your iframe code for embedding, nor have you mentioned if your browser's console or network tab shows any errors.

Comment: Edit your iframe code into your question, don't post it as a comment (delete your previous comment).

Comment: Is that literally the code you're using to embed your iframe? HTML doesn't use square brackets. It uses angle brackets and attributes, similar to XML. Unless that's specific Wordpress syntax, which I'm not familiar with? Are you embedding via HTML?

Comment: yes, it is wordpress plugin code. But, it do same thing, I guess. I can change iframe to any code to get external site working! I am not bound with any iframe code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your web.config (if hosted on IIS 7.0 or later):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Frame-Options" /> <!-- optional -->
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This must be added in the application being "framed" (in your case an asp.net app), not in the parent app (wordpress).

Reference: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol